# how to check if update date is greater then current date in android studio java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, date, drawable

I want to change the background drawable of a specific table row based on their status compared to their updated date/time with the current time and check if it has been 24h since last update date/time and set a different background drawable.

What I got so far works but I can't figure out how to check if its been 24h and not just greater then the current time

```
   JobRepository jobRepository = new JobRepository(a.getApplication());
        jobRepository.findEnquiry().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), jobsEnquiry -> {
        TableRow[] tableRows = new TableRow[jobsEnquiry.size()];

        for (int i=0; i<jobsEnquiry.size(); i++) {
            Job job = jobsEnquiry.get(i).job;
            tableRows[i] = new TableRow(a);
            tableRows[i].setId(i + 1);
            tableRows[i].setPadding(0,20,0,20);
            if(job.getStatus().equals("Left message/Awaiting reply")){
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd H:m:s");
                Date updatedDate = job.getUpdatedAt();
                Date date = job.getDate();
                Date currentTime = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
                tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_outline);

                if (updatedDate.getTime() < currentTime.getTime()){
                    tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                    tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_outline_status);
                }

            }
            else if(job.getStatus().equals("Action required")){
                tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.list_selector_background);
                tableRows[i].setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.table_outline_status);
            }
```

Comment: Can't you use `java.time` for a task like this? Why use the outdated `java.util.Date`?

Comment: This is what works for now and the ```job.getUpdatedAt()``` requires a date plus I am not familiar with ```java.time```

Comment: OK, I see... Refactoring huge loads of code is nothing one would prefer, but `java.time` is a real improvement. Will be worth having a look at...

Comment: Additionally that's quite bad from a performance standpoint. Creating a SimpleDateFormat on each iteration is ... expensive. Lots of mixed responsibilities, not to mention you're basically ignoring timezones, and offsets, so a change of time (like daylight saving) can yield incorrect results in this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returning value from `getTime()` on a `Date` class is a `long` see: https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Date#getTime()

So the below code would work, but it wouldn't handle timezones very well.

```
private final long TWENTYFOUR_HOURS = TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24);

if ((updatedDate.getTime() + TWENTYFOUR_HOURS) < currentTime.getTime()){
//Do something
}
```

or

```
if ((updatedDate.getTime() + TimeUnit.HOURS.toMillis(24)) < currentTime.getTime()){
//Do something
}
```

Comment: I think its fine as long as it works after 24h from ```updatedDate.getTime()``` which seems to be working well so far.
Thank you

Comment: Hmm yeah if i set a different date for the ```updatedDate``` it wont actually work

Comment: No worries, if it's the accepted answer, please mark it as so. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

### java.time through desugaring

Consider using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date and time work. Also when you get olkd-fashioned `Date` objects from a legacy API. Convert each `Date` to a modern `Instant` first thing.

```
    Instant twentyfourHoursAgo = Instant.now().minus(24, ChronoUnit.HOURS);
    List<Date> dates = Arrays.asList(new Date(1_624_298_359_544L), new Date(1_624_240_459_544L),
            new Date(1_624_377_259_544L), new Date(1_624_297_759_544L));
    for (Date updatedDate : dates) {
        Instant updatedInstant = DateTimeUtils.toInstant(updatedDate);
        if (updatedInstant.isAfter(twentyfourHoursAgo)) {
            System.out.println("" + updatedDate + ": updated within 24 hours");
        } else {
            System.out.println("" + updatedDate + ": it has been 24 hours since last update");
        }
    }
```

Output when I ran the code in Europe/Copenhagen time zone a minute ago:

> ```
> Mon Jun 21 19:59:19 CEST 2021: updated within 24 hours
> Mon Jun 21 03:54:19 CEST 2021: it has been 24 hours since last update
> Tue Jun 22 17:54:19 CEST 2021: updated within 24 hours
> Mon Jun 21 19:49:19 CEST 2021: it has been 24 hours since last update
> ```

I have coded for ThreeTen Backport (see below). It offers `DateTimeUtils` for converting between old-fashioned and modern types. If using either desugaring or native java.time the conversion from `Date` to `Instant` is a little bit simpler, just `updatedDate.toInstant()` (the `toInstant` method was added to `Date` in Java 8).

### Question: Doesn’t java.time require Android API level 26?

java.time works nicely on both older and newer Android devices. It just requires at least **Java 6**.

- In Java 8 and later and on newer Android devices (from API level 26) the modern API comes built-in.
- In non-Android Java 6 and 7 get the ThreeTen Backport, the backport of the modern classes (ThreeTen for JSR 310; see the links at the bottom).
- On older Android either use desugaring or the Android edition of ThreeTen Backport. It’s called ThreeTenABP. In the latter case make sure you import the date and time classes from `org.threeten.bp` with subpackages.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table)
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: This is very informative, I will give it a try. Thank you.